# If $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$, prove that $\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}$ is the countable union of sets with finite $\mu$-measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Tonight I am working on the following problem:

> Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space and $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$.  Prove that $$\{x\in X: f(x)\neq 0\}$$ is the countable union of sets with finite $\mu$-measure.

My first reaction was to write down the definition of what it means for $f$ to be in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$:

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{S},\mu)$ is a measure space.  An $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ is contained in $\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ if $$||f||_1=\int|f|\,d\mu<\infty.$$

Okay, so $\int|f|\,d\mu<\infty$.  How does this help me?  I'm not sure.  After alot of searching, I read on what it means for a measure $\mu$ to be [*$\sigma$-finite*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure).  That got me thinking -- does $f\in\mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ imply that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite?  If so, then I think I could easily prove this using any of the conditions outlined in that Wikipedia page.

Am I on the right track?  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a standard "layer cake" argument. Define
$$E_n=\{x\in X\,|\, |f(x)|\ge \frac{1}{n}\}$$
and note that $\mu(E_n)$ must be finite, or $f$ would not be in $L^1$. But the union of all the $E_n$ is exactly the set where $f$ is nonzero.

Comment: Ah, interesting!  So where do the $E_n$'s live?  In $\mathcal{S}$?  Also, what is the intuition behind defining $E_n$ like that?  Why do we care where $|f(x)|\geq \frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: The $E_n$s are measurable subsets of $X$, so they are elements of $\mathcal S$. We define the $E_n$ in this way because they have to have finite measure, and if $f(x)\neq 0$, $x$ would have to be in some $E_n$ by the Archimedean principle.